# Storing Index value of a column in table and use it in other function/part of a code using cypress

Tags: cypress

I am trying to store the index value of column and trying to reuse it in other parts of code, but i am unable to do it. Can you please help me. I have attached the code as pic.i tired just by creating a variable and using alias. Both are not working.[image]

Comment: Please avoid adding screenshot of the code. Add the actual code to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the header column index from `invoke('index')`

```js
paginationElements.tableHeaderRows().contains('Source device')
  .find('th').contains('Source device')
  .invoke('index')                      // index of <th> in headerRow
  .as('indexValueSourceDevice')

cy.get('@indexValueSourceDevice').then(indexValueSourceDevice => {
  // for example, tbody cell for Source Device
  cy.get('tbody tr td').eq(indexValueSourceDevice)
    .should('eq', ...)
})
```

Comment: eq(indexValueSourceDevice) says jquery element can not be assigned to number, that's the problem I am facing

Comment: It looks like your photograph is not correctly representing the test. I see there that `ind: number` yet you get an error saying it's not a number. Can you explain it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the value from an alias you have to do this:

```js
cy.wrap(ind).as('indexValueSourceDevice') //saves value with alias

//retrieve the value from alias
cy.get('@indexValueSourceDevice').then((indexValueSourceDevice) => {
  
  //indexValueSourceDevice is available here
  cy.log(indexValueSourceDevice) //logs it
})
```

Comment: Yeah I did this, but again I will have to compare the index (alias) value with other index, like cy.get('@indexValueSourceDevice').then((indexValueSourceDevice) => {
  
  //indexValueSourceDevice is available here
  If(index === indexValueSourceDevice)  //here index is from other loop , getting error like "condtion always false , since types 'number' and jquery element has no overlap" can you help me to resolve this
})

Comment: It is very difficult to read the code from screenshot. it would be good if you add your code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

cy.get('@indexValueSourceDevice').then((indexValueSourceDevice) => { let indexReq = parseInt(indexValueSourceDevice.tostring()) If(index === indexReq){ //EXEXUTE CODE }}) This is working thanks to all for your help